How can I recursively unzip files that matches a pattern in a group of nested ZIP files?
I have a bunch of zip files, with several levels of zip files inside them.
I only want to extract files that matches this pattern: "_dnbr6.tif" and they can be located at different levels of the zip/directories hierarchy.
One extra hint is that the files I'm looking for are located in directories/zip files (inside zip files) named like "fire_bundle". Lower and upper case changes on different zip/directories.
How can I do it without extracting all the files of each of the nested zip files?
I guess the idea is to:

Iterate over each zip file listing all the files inside, if my file pattern matches then extract it.

If not, match my zip pattern (fire_bundle) and extract only that zip file and recursively look for my file pattern (list the files inside that zip, etc.)


I still don't know how to do the recursive part, so any help is appreciated.

Are you saying you have zip files inside of zip files? That is going to make hard, if not impossible, to look at the contents of the embedded zip files.

Thanks... I improved the description of my issue. I guess it's more about matching two patterns, extracting them, and for one pattern recursively run the function/process again.

Here is a script that will recursively search all the .zip files within the starting .zip file looking for the target file "_dnbr6.tif".
#!/bin/bash

targetFile="_dnbr6.tif"
sandboxDir="sandbox"

usage () {
  cat <<EOF
Usage $(basename $0) zipfile

This script will extract all the target files ($targetFile) from the provided
.zip file, including any that are in embedded in any .zip files included within it.
It puts all the files in a sandbox directory name $sandboxDir. This directory
must not already exist.
EOF
}

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  usage
  exit 1
fi

if [ -d $sandboxDir ]; then
  echo "Error, the sandbox directory $sandboxDir already exists."
  echo
  usage
  exit 1
fi

mkdir $sandboxDir
cd $sandboxDir
startDir=$(pwd)

# Extract the initial .zip file looking for either the target file or additional .zip files.
unzip -q ../$1 "*.zip" "*$targetFile" 2>&1 | fgrep -v "filename not matched"   # Suppress the "filename not matched" message.

zipFiles="../$1"   # Just set to get past the first interation of the while loop.
#
# Loop until there aren't any .zip files anymore.
while [ ! -z "$zipFiles" ]; do
  zipFiles=$(find . -name '*.zip')
  if [ ! -z "$zipFiles" ]; then
    #
    # For each .zip file, extract any .zip files and the target file.
    for zipFile in $zipFiles; do
      cd $(dirname $zipFile)
      unzip -q ${startDir}/$zipFile "*.zip" "*$targetFile" 2>&1 | fgrep -v "filename not matched"
      rm ${startDir}/$zipFile
      cd $startDir
    done
  fi
done

echo "The target file '$targetFile' was extracted here:"
cd ..
find $sandboxDir -name "$targetFile"


this is amazing. I learnt several new things about bash scripting in this example. Thanks!!!

From unzip man page:

file(s)]
An optional list of archive members to be processed, separated by spaces. (VMS versions compiled with VMSCLI defined must delimit files with commas instead. See -v in OPTIONS below.) Regular expressions (wildcards) may be used to match multiple members; see above. Again, be sure to quote expressions that would otherwise be expanded or modified by the operating system.

So, you can use wildcards as long as you escape them.
